# Should I add any specific markup or tag for automatically transcribed content to avoid SEO issues?

Tags: seo

I am adding some educational PDF embedded files into an educational blog (not all the content is made up of pure pdf files, there are a lot of great posts written with love and care too). To improve SEO, I am adding an automated transcription under the document with an OCR version of the PDF content.

This automated transcription doesn't include perfect sentences. If you would read that without the PDF you could say: "What is this?", in some cases. Though, some of them include quite long texts that make total sense. It depends on the PDF.

I am adding this so that search engines can read the page and know what it's about, because just embedding a PDF... would mean it's a blank page for search engines.

I wonder if there is anything I can do to let search engines know that it's an automated transcription and it's not supposed to be processed as "perfect main content".
Is there anything else I should note in this case? Do you know any similar site that handles it excellently?

The most similar site I know is called studocu ([example page with transcription here](https://www.studocu.com/my/document/inti-international-university/english-language-skills/studocu-example-of-english-essay-for-english-writing-skills-assessment-semester-2/21114434)), and it also adds everything into a "transcription" box.